# Override template using local xml file Magento

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.8

I want to override following code to my local.xml

> ```
> <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
>     <reference name="product.info.simple.extra">
>         <block type="cataloginventory/stockqty_default" template="cataloginventory/stockqty/default.phtml"/>
>     </reference>
> </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
> ```

The issue is that if the block type doesnot have any name here. Basically i want to use different template in place of default.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

Since the block 'product.info.extrahint' is only used to display the stockqty_default block, I'd suggest just unsetting product.info.extrahint and re-adding it with the stockqty block with a different template.

Like this;

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>extrahint</name></action>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
        <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
        <block type="cataloginventory/stockqty_default" name="stockqty_default" template="cataloginventory/stockqty/custom_default_template.phtml"/>
    </block>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

That should do it.

Mind you, if there are other extensions that add blocks to this block, they might be removed (depending on the load order of the extensions).